# How to find largest file in the subdirectories?

Tags: linux, command-line, sed, awk

Wit the following command I can find largest directory.

```
find <directory> -printf '%s %p\n' |sort -nr | head
```

But is there a way to find largest file within all the subdirectories in directory ?

Answer (score 12):

Specify `-type f` for file:

```
find -type f -printf '%s %p\n' |sort -nr | head
```

Answer (score 0):

With the command you just gave, you get the largest file. If you want to summarize the size for each file recursively for directories you may want to use the `du' command.

Comment: du -xak .|sort -n|tail -50